# How to get the average by oldest date sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE Consultation (
idConsultation number,
dateConsultation date NOT NULL,
prixConsultation number(4,2),
pouls number(3),
size number(3),
poids number(3),
pressionSystolique number(3),
pressionDiastolique number(3),
idMedecin number(3),
idPatient number(3),
);
```

A patient can appear more than one time in this table, and the consultation has a date.

I want to get the average of the size as a result, and respect the fact that we can only take the older date of the consultation per patient.

Thanks in advance, and this is what I came with but not working...

```
SELECT AVG(size)
FROM Consultation
WHERE dateConsultation = (SELECT MAX(dateConsultation) FROM Consultation);
```

Comment: Where is the column `taille`??

Comment: Please clarify, do you want a  certain condition or to aggregrate the results?

Comment: not very clear what you are asking here, maybe you can show some sample data and expected result set

Comment: Like walther stated, you obviously have some typos here or there -- there is no `taille` column

Comment: size column * I forgot to edit it sorry

Comment: Older date will be MIN(DateColumn) , MAX(DateColumn) will give you the latest date. Also if you pick one value the Oldest or the Latest date , Average will be the value itself, not sure what you are trying to achieve by this

Comment: I know but I want to get the average with every latest consultation for every patient (patient is represented by idPatient)..

Comment: plz, clarify me if you use one result for consultation, why is there an avg of the one resulting size row? and its meaning is..?

Comment: So in other words you can say, you want the average of their size excluding the latest appointment they attended ?

Comment: M.Ali is the exact thing I want to say, but I want to exclude the oldest appointment and calculate the average only with the latest.

Comment: In that case I have answered your question correctly.

Comment: The CREATE TABLE statement has errors. First, there should not be a comma at the end of the last column definition. Second, `size` is not a valid column name (it's a reserved word). Please edit your question, correct the syntax errors, include some test data, and also include the results you're getting, what's wrong with them, and the results you expect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to first get the `max(dateConsultation)` per `idPatient`, and then use that to filter your `avg(size)` `select`. You can do this using a subquery and an `inner join`:

```
select avg(c.size) as avgSizeLatestConsultation
from Consultation as c
    inner join (select
                    idPatient,
                    max(dateConsultation) as LatestConsultation
                from Consultation
                group by
                    idPatient) as d
         on d.idPatient = c.idPatient
         and d.LatestConsultation = c.dateConsultation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
 SELECT * 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idPatient ORDER BY dateConsultation) rn 
 FROM Consultation 
)
SELECT idPatient 
      ,AVG(size) Avg_Size
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn > 1
GROUP BY idPatient;
```

Comment: FROM keyword not found where expected ?

Comment: Oracle, SQL Developper

Answer (score 0):

Given this test data:

```
INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(1,  10, TO_DATE('01-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(2,  10, TO_DATE('02-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(3,  11, TO_DATE('03-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(4,  12, TO_DATE('04-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(5,  13, TO_DATE('05-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(6,  13, TO_DATE('06-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 2);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(7,  13, TO_DATE('07-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 3);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(8,  14, TO_DATE('08-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(9,  15, TO_DATE('09-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 1);

INSERT INTO CONSULTATION (IDCONSULTATION, IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION, "size")
  VALUES(10, 15, TO_DATE('10-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 12);
```

the following query produces the correct result (`AVG_SIZE = 1`):

```
SELECT AVG("size") AS AVG_SIZE
  FROM CONSULTATION
  WHERE IDCONSULTATION IN (SELECT IDCONSULTATION
                             FROM CONSULTATION
                             WHERE (IDPATIENT, DATECONSULTATION) IN
                               (SELECT IDPATIENT, MIN(DATECONSULTATION) AS DATECONSULTATION
                                  FROM CONSULTATION
                                  GROUP BY IDPATIENT));
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6eff0/1).

Share and enjoy.